# finding size of multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

How would I find the size in bytes of an array like this?

```
    double dArray[2][5][3][4];
```

I've tried this method but it returns "2". Maybe because the array is only declared and not filled with anything?

```
     #include <iostream>
     #define ARRAY_SIZE(array) (sizeof((array))/sizeof((array[0])))
     using namespace std;

      int main() {
        double dArray[2][5][3][4];
        cout << ARRAY_SIZE(dArray) << endl;
       }
```

Comment: do you want the size in terms of bytes or the size in terms of how many elements are in the entire array?

Comment: To get the total number of elements in an array (here: 2*5*3*4), you can use something like `template<class T> constexpr std::size_t get_element_count(T const& a) { return sizeof(T)/sizeof(typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type); }`

Answer (score 5):

> How would I find the size in bytes

This tells you how many *elements* are present in an array.  And it gives the expected answer of `2` for `dArray`.

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(array) (sizeof((array))/sizeof((array[0])))
```

If what you want it the *byte count*, this will do it.

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(array) (sizeof(array))
```

> Maybe because the array is only declared and not filled with anything?

That won't affect the behavior of `sizeof`.  An array has no concept of *filled* or *not filled*.

Comment: Is there a reason for the double brackets in the first macro `((array))`?

Comment: @DyP No functional reason that I'm aware of.  It's the code presented in the question.  :)

Comment: Pretty sure OP is having more trouble getting 2*5*3*4 than converting from elem to bytes.

Comment: One could argue the name of the first macro would be clearer if it was `ARRAY_LENGTH` (or `ARRAY_EXTENT`). Also, there's the C++11 approach using `std::extent`, like `template<class T> constexpr std::size_t get_extent(T const& a) { return std::extent<T>::value; }`

Comment: OIC.  Nevermind, this is right - problem is array[0] was giant so OP should have been dividing by sizeof array[0][0][0][0] to get elem count.

Answer (score 2):

`array[0]` contains `5 * 3 * 4` elements so `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])` will give you `2` when the first dimension of your array is 2

Rewrite your macro as:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(array, type) (sizeof((array))/sizeof((type)))
```

to get the number of elements,

or simply `sizeof(array)` to get the number of bytes.